# Apache Rewrite to Alter URI Path

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I'm new to Apache and I'm having trouble understanding Rewrite rules.

On my test server I have an arbitrary Apache config which serves up an Elasticsearch instance to select IPs.

What I have so far is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName home.mytest.server

ProxyPass /esearch http://127.0.0.1:9200
ProxyPassReverse /esearch http://127.0.0.1.9200

<Location /esearch>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from <my IP>
</Location>

<Location /esearch/*/_search>
    #Alter URI in here
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from <my IP>
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

What I want to do is rewrite all requests to `/esearch/*/_search` to include a default value in the path. So `/esearch/*/_search` is rewritten to `/esearch/myIndex/*/_search`.

How do I do this? I've read up about the RewriteConditions and Rules but it's not really sinking in.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following instead of the `ProxyPass` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/esearch/([^/]+)/(_search.*) http://127.0.0.1:9200/myIndex/$1/$2 [P]
RewriteRule ^/esearch/?(.*) http://127.0.0.1:9200/$1 [P]
```

This uses mod_rewrite in combination with mod_proxy (`P` flag) to rewrite/proxy the request.

You only need your first `<location /esearch>` container.

> So `/esearch/*/_search` is rewritten to `/esearch/myIndex/*/_search`

However, according to your earlier `ProxyPass` directive, this is *proxied* to `/myIndex/*/_search`. Which is what the mod_rewrite directive attempts to do.